# Python pandas, how to find the min after max in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to find the min value/index in the rows that are after the max value location. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"c1": [22, 55, 48, 30, 35], "c2": [6, 2, 33, 22, 17]})
df

    c1  c2
0   22  6
1   55  2
2   48  33
3   30  22
4   35  17
```

For c1, I need the min after max value 55, for c2, I need the min after max value 33, so the desired result should be

```
c1 30
c2 17
```

Obviously I could get idxmax first and pass to an apply function. Is there a simpler/efficient way and avoiding the apply function? I may have thousands of columns.
Appreciate the help....

Answer (score 4):

We can use `max` then do the `cummax`

```
s=df.where(df.eq(df.max()).cummax()).min()
Out[243]: 
c1    30.0
c2    17.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for. Cool stuff. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"c1": [22, 55, 48, 30, 35], "c2": [6, 2, 33, 22, 17]})

col_name = 'c1'
max_index = df[col_name].argmax()
min_index = max_index + 1 + df[col_name].iloc[max_index + 1:].argmin()
df[col_name].iloc[min_index]  # 30

col_name = 'c2'
max_index = df[col_name].argmax()
min_index = max_index + 1 + df[col_name].iloc[max_index + 1:].argmin()
df[col_name].iloc[min_index]  # 17
```

Note that `pd.Series.argmax` and `pd.Series.argmin` return the index of the first max (or min) only. If there are multiple max or min values, this may need to be adjusted.

Also, this won't work if max is in the last row but we can modify it to return None or let it throw an error if that's expected.

Comment: Functionality-wise, it would work, with a fix: min_index = df[col_name].iloc[max_index + 1:].argmin(). But looping through the columns, similar to the apply function, wouldn't be runtime efficient. YOBEN_S's solution earlier is nice.